# Proper web method response length handling

Tags: c#, webrequest

there is one web method in my server. It returns a simple json with approximately 100-200 records (20-30 fields per record).

The result is not big.

But a new requirement is to add one field which is a Base64Encoded string.

The base64encode string is converted from an image (maximum 10MB).

I would like to ask if it is proper to put the image string to the json and thus 1 API (then the json can go to 1000MB-2000MB at maximum).

Or it should split the image (big package) to a new API and request the image string one by one after response of first API is retrieved?

Or there is better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

What i would do first is to have a simple paging functionality.

Secound i would just make an `id Link` something like `getImage?id=5`.

When the json is to big it will take to much time to post it, and also having an image in json is simple not a smart idee, think about it. The image a `byte[]` when converting it to json it will try and convert it to base64string which will take time.

Time consuming for json convert and also posting the json.

So an `id Link` is the best solution i could find.

```js
public class Product{
 public int Id { get; set; }

 public string Name { get; set; }

 [JsonIgnore]
 public byte[] Image { get; set }
}

// controller 

public List<Product> Get(){
 return db.Products.ToList();
}

public FileResult GetImage(int id){
  var img = db.Products.First(x=> x.Id == id).Image;
  return File(img, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "test");
}

/// now lets say that you present your product with js as an example

var products = getProductByAjax();
products.forEach(x=> {
// and here is the image 
var img = "<img src=/Home/GetImage?id="+x.Id+" />";
})
```

Comment: the image is from another system, i dont think it can provide a GET url for their image

Comment: Well you are getting the image from the servet right? you could provide somthing like static/Session variable to save the images with keys temporary. or you may get the whole object from the server that containe the image. it will be `getImage?objectId=5`

Comment: i dont think it has anything different of using id link or POST. i need to get its base64encoded string anyway, the image need to be stored in my system

Comment: Well yah but instead of inc the image in the object when you get 100 items at once, instead render the object and then call the image one by one

Comment: is that means the approach equals to "split image data to another API"? or i missed something else? thanks

Comment: Here i wrote an example, have a look

Comment: the image service provider is not a must C#, it is not possible to not parse the image into base64encoded string for transportation between 2 systems. your example is local to local which does not match my scenario:)

Comment: at most i can request the image service provider to implement 1 more API for my system to fetch the image separated from the original request.

Comment: You are atill not understanding the idee, it dose not matter if it a server or a local to local. you could count the db as the external server. or `getProductByAjax` is another server. so at least you have to seperate the products and the images, too have the best performance. Well i tried.

Comment: do you mean my service provider will provide an URL like getImage?id=5. and my API fetches this URL, and store in my system?

Comment: i think i need to store it into my system